# Integration of a square root inside another square root function.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Integrate the following $$\int_0^5 \sqrt{5-\sqrt{x}} \ \mathrm{d}x$$ I have done the following:

I got the expression under the square root to equal $$5-x^{1/2}$$ so the integral then becomes $$\int_0^5 \left(5-x^{1/2}\right)^{1/2}\ \mathrm{d}x$$ Here is where I am stuck. Do I need to use some variation of the binomial theorem here?

I hope my use of MathJax was "up-to-code" here. I apologize if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can make the $u$-substitution $$u=5-\sqrt{x}$$ and solve for $x$ here. We get $x=(u-5)^2$ so $$\mathrm{d}x=(2u-10) \ \mathrm{d}u$$ Now to find the new bounds we use $u=5-\sqrt{x}$. So the bounds are $u=5-\sqrt{0} =5$ and $u=5-\sqrt{5}$. The integral is now $$\int_5^{5-\sqrt{5}}\! \sqrt{u} \cdot (2u-10)\ \mathrm{d}u$$ Which is easy to solve.

Comment: I now make $\sqrt{u}=u^{1/2}$ and expand correct?

Comment: @JamesCooper yes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: substitute $u=5-\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The substitution $u=5-\sqrt x$, i.e. $x=(5-u)^2$ yields 
$$
\int \sqrt u (-2(5-u))\,du
$$
for some new limits that I'm not going to compute right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is another easier method

Let $\sqrt{5-\sqrt{x}}=u\implies \frac{-1}{4\sqrt x\sqrt{5-\sqrt x}}\ dx=du$ or $dx=4u(u^2-5)\ du$, 
$$\int_0^5 \sqrt{5-\sqrt x}\ dx=\int_{\sqrt 5}^{\sqrt{5-\sqrt 5}} u(4u(u^2-5))\ du$$
$$=4\int_{\sqrt 5}^{\sqrt{5-\sqrt 5}} (u^4-5u^2)\ du$$
$$=4\left(\frac{u^5}{5}-\frac{5u^3}{3}\right)_{\sqrt 5}^{\sqrt{5-\sqrt 5}}$$
$$=4\left(\frac{(5-\sqrt 5)^{5/2}}{5}-\frac{5(5-\sqrt 5)^{3/2}}{3}-\frac{25\sqrt5}{5}+\frac{25\sqrt 5}{3}\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{\left(\frac{(5-\sqrt 5)^{5/2}}{5}-\frac{5(5-\sqrt 5)^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{10\sqrt5}{3}\right)}$$

Comment: How is this an "easier" method

Comment: because each term of of integrand has integer power

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot the bounds of integration aren't integers so you're comparing apples to oranges. Quite frankly, Nikhil's answer is the cleaner substitution and requires less work before integrating (e.g. your expression for $du$ is frightening)

Comment: Yeah, that's one's own perspective